# At Least Once Delivery Semantics on a Graph with a record multiplier

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am using Akka Streams 2.4.8 against Kafka and trying to construct graphs with At Least Once Delivery Semantics. Several of my graphs start out with something like the following:

```
 committableSource ~> processing ~> mapOneRecordToNOtherRecords ~> ...
```

where `mapOneRecordToNOtherRecords` takes a single message and transforms it into an arbitrary number "N" of messages of another type to work with. That means that when I'm done with this stage, each incoming message has been multiplied into N messages, each of which has the same `CommittableOffset`. The issue is, in order to support ALOS, I need to wait to commit until the last of these is finished its processing step.

Now I have been using `Flow#mapConcat` to handle the output from `mapOneRecordToNOtherRecords` and continue downstream. It is my understanding that the output from `mapConcat` preserves order, so what I need is a graph element that collects N messages with a given correlation identifier (such as the `CommittableOffset`) and emits the last of them when all are collected.

The method `Flow#groupBy` looks interesting for this purpose, but has no shutoff valve and I don't see any criteria by which it might shed keys - nor the criteria by which it decides to emit for a given key. Other SO posts have led me to believe that its use may indeed create memory leaks.

I've been poring through docs for some other solution, but I'm not finding any. Can anyone point me to it? Surely this is a common requirement? Or do I have to build a custom `GraphStage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case the answer is (as I suspect) not to be found in the docs for Akka, I wrote a custom `GraphStage` to do it.  Here it is

```
/**
 * Accumulates records in order based on a propertyExtractor function and a complete function. Preserves order of incoming such that if a group of
 * messages with property value P2 completes before a group with P1, and the first P1 was pulled before the first P2, they are not pushed until the
 * P1s complete. If this has not happened within timeout, will throw a TimeoutException
 *
 * @param propertyExtractor   finds the property on the object being sent by which to track incoming
 * @param complete            establishes criteria by which the accumulated sequence of records may be emitted back to the stream
 * @param complete            (optional, default 10 seconds) duration over which stage will wait for an earlier value before throwing a 
 *                                   TimeoutException 
 * @tparam E                   the type of the record
 * @tparam P                   the type of the property acting as a key for the record
 */
final class AccumulateWhileNotFull[E, P](propertyExtractor: E => P, bufferFull: (Seq[E]) => Boolean, timeout: Duration = 10 seconds) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[E, Seq[E]]] {

  val in = Inlet[E]("AccumulateWhileUnchanged.in")
  val out = Outlet[Seq[E]]("AccumulateWhileUnchanged.out")

  override def shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

    private val buffers = TrieMap[P, scala.collection.mutable.Builder[E, Vector[E]]]()
    private val ordering = mutable.LinkedHashSet[P]()
    private val timing = TrieMap[P, DateTime]()

    setHandlers(in, out, new InHandler with OutHandler {

      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        //add next element to the buffer it requires
        val nextElement = grab(in)
        val nextState = propertyExtractor(nextElement)
        val bufferForNextState = buffers.getOrElseUpdate(nextState, Vector.newBuilder[E])
        bufferForNextState += nextElement

        //track the next state allowed to be pushed
        ordering += nextState

        val allowedState = ordering.head
        val firstAllowedAt = timing.getOrElseUpdate(allowedState, DateTime.now)

        if (firstAllowedAt.isBefore(DateTime.now().minus(timeout.toMillis))) {
          //reset timer in case exception is to be ignored
          timing += allowedState -> DateTime.now
          throw new TimeoutException(s"Failed to process expected number of messages for property ${allowedState} within ${timeout}")
        }

        if (nextState != allowedState) {
          addToBuffersAndPull(nextState, bufferForNextState)
          val bufferForAllowedState = buffers.getOrElseUpdate(allowedState, Vector.newBuilder[E]).result().toSeq
          if (bufferFull(bufferForAllowedState)) {
            removeFromBuffersAndPush(allowedState, bufferForAllowedState)
          }
        }
        else {
          //they are the same
          val result = bufferForNextState.result().toSeq
          if (bufferFull(result)) {
            removeFromBuffersAndPush(allowedState, result)
          }
          else {
            addToBuffersAndPull(nextState, bufferForNextState)
          }
        }

      }

      private def removeFromBuffersAndPush(state: P, result: Seq[E]) = {
        buffers -= state
        ordering -= state
        timing -= state
        push(out, result)
      }

      private def addToBuffersAndPull(state: P, builder: mutable.Builder[E, Vector[E]]) = {
        buffers += state -> builder
        pull(in)
      }

      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        pull(in)
      }

      override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
        var continuing = true
        //go in order, first one not full shuts it all down
        ordering.foreach { p =>
          val result = buffers(p).result()
          continuing = continuing && bufferFull(result)
          if (continuing) {
            emit(out, result)
          }
        }
        completeStage()
      }
    })

    override def postStop(): Unit = {
      buffers.clear()
    }
  }
}
```

And the integration test to back it up is

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ ActorMaterializer, Materializer }
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{ Flow, Source }
import akka.stream.testkit.scaladsl.TestSink
import akka.testkit.TestKit
import org.scalatest.{ FunSuiteLike, Matchers }

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class AccumulateWhileNotFullTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("AccumulateWhileNotFullTest")) with FunSuiteLike with Matchers {
  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  test("test works singly") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 1)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("a", 1, 1)))
    Try(result.requestNext()).isFailure should be(true)
  }

  test("test works with never complete") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 2)))
    Try(result.requestNext()).isFailure should be(true)
  }

  test("test resets keys") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 1), Thing("a", 1, 1)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("a", 1, 1)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("a", 1, 1)))
    Try(result.requestNext()).isFailure should be(true)
  }

  test("test accumulates multiple in a row") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 3), Thing("a", 5, 3), Thing("a", 10, 3)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("a", 1, 3), Thing("a", 5, 3), Thing("a", 10, 3)))
    Try(result.requestNext()).isFailure should be(true)
  }

  test("test accumulates multiple in order") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 3), Thing("a", 5, 3), Thing("a", 10, 3), Thing("b", 5, 2), Thing("b", 10, 2)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("a", 1, 3), Thing("a", 5, 3), Thing("a", 10, 3)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("b", 5, 2), Thing("b", 10, 2)))
    Try(result.requestNext()).isFailure should be(true)
  }

  test("test handles out of order correctly") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 3), Thing("b", 5, 2), Thing("a", 5, 3), Thing("c", 5, 1), Thing("a", 10, 3), Thing("b", 10, 2)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("a", 1, 3), Thing("a", 5, 3), Thing("a", 10, 3)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("b", 5, 2), Thing("b", 10, 2)))
    result.requestNext() should be(Seq(Thing("c", 5, 1)))
    Try(result.requestNext()).isFailure should be(true)
  }

  test("test timeout throws exception") {
    var result = runBasic(List(Thing("a", 1, 2)), 1 seconds)
    val initalTry = Try(result.requestNext())
    initalTry.isFailure should be(true)
    initalTry.recover { case ex: Throwable => ex.getMessage should be("expected OnNext, found OnComplete") } //test probe stock exception
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    Try(result.requestNext()).recover { case ex: TimeoutException => ex.getMessage should be(s"Failed to process expected number of messages for property a within 1 seconds") }
  }

  def runBasic(things: List[Thing], timeout: Duration = 10 seconds)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) = {
    val f: Flow[Thing, Seq[Thing], _] = Flow.fromGraph(new AccumulateWhileNotFull[Thing, String](
      in => in.prop,
      vals => vals.headOption.map { v => vals.size == v.count }.getOrElse(false),
      timeout
    ))
    var result = List[Seq[Thing]]()
    Source.fromIterator(() => things.toIterator).via(f).runWith(TestSink.probe(actorSystem))

  }

  case class Thing(prop: String, value: Int, count: Int)

}
```